# SQL Server 2022: Latest Update CU6 - Why does Last_Value does not work when there is no Partition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, gaps-and-islands, sql-null

Can anyone explain why Last_Value does not take the last value (which is last as per order by) for all rows ?

select * from mytableone

[Initial Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmNGx.jpg)

(Please click on link)

**Query Used:**

select t.*,

LAST_VALUE(PAST_DUE_COL) OVER (Order by ID) as New_Due_Col

from

mytableone t

[Actual Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg8D3.jpg)
(Please click on link)

Expecting that all 4 rows of result column-3 should have same value -

'0-30 days past due'

Can someone explain the reason ?

Comment: FYI, images attract downvotes. Include data in the form of a formatted table or INSERT statements.

Answer (score 1):

When `ORDER BY` is specified, the [default window frame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#order-by) is `UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`. Your query is functionally identical to:

```
SELECT t.*, LAST_VALUE(PAST_DUE_COL) OVER (Order by ID RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as New_Due_Col
FROM mytableone t;
```

so `LAST_VALUE` will be the current row value.

Specify `UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` to get the LAST_VALUE over the entire result:

```
SELECT t.*, LAST_VALUE(PAST_DUE_COL) OVER (Order by ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as New_Due_Col
FROM mytableone t;
```